# update ss utility on centos

Tags: centos, yum

My centos version is:

> 2.6.32-131.17.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Oct 6 19:24:09 BST 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

And my `ss` version:

```
ss --version
ss utility, iproute2-ss091226
```

I need to update to version that I have on my Ubuntu machine :

```
ss --version
ss utility, iproute2-ss131122
```

How can I update the version (tried `yum install ss`)?

Comment: tried yum update? should update packages

Comment: I can't find ss in yum update and I don't want to update other packages, it is a production machine.

Comment: ss is part of iproute package and its version must match the kernel version on the running system since they're simple user land tools that communicate with the kernel. If you're looking for some functionality that exists on newer versions it's quite probable (if not certain) that that functionality is simply missing from the kernel version you're running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ss` is not in a package called `ss`.  If you run:

```
yum provides */ss
```

you will be shown a list of packages that provide the `ss` utility.  A quick read through this will show that the package that provides `ss` is `iproute`.

You could possibly use a website such as http://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/index.html to search for later versions of `iptroute` and install that.

The problem with this approach is that later packages will have dependencies that you don't have installed on CentOS 6.  You will therefore need to install those too.  After a while you'll end up with a hotchpotch system with various versions of utilities and libraries that haven't been thoroughly tested with each other which will only give you a great deal of pain, especially when you attempt an `yum update` later.

An alternative is to compile it yourself.  There are various resources available on the internet.  You can either compile and install, or you can compile and create an RPM which you then install on your system. However, compiling will necessitate the installation of many utilities and libraries on your system if you haven't compiled before.

Another option would be to use [Copr build system](https://copr.fedoraproject.org/) to compile remotely for you.  You create a `src.rpm` for `iptables` and send it to `copr` for building.  Creating a `src.rpm` is relatively easy.  Even easier, is editing already created `src.rpm` files from other systems, such as CentOS 7 or Feodra 20.  Information on `src.rpm` is available from the [Fedora Wiki](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package), [Fedora Docs](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch11s03.html) and [CentOS site](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/RebuildSRPM) and, of course, on Google.

Edit the `.spec` file within the `src.rpm` to reflect the version of the package you want to install, remembering that a certain version of a package (such as `iproute`) may well need certain version of other libraries installed.  In this case, you'll end up in the same situation as if you'd downloaded the `rpm` from RPM Find.net above.  However, using this method gives you slightly more control.

Answer (score 0):

ss is provided by package `iproute` from the official RHEL rpm's repository. The latest version Red Hat provides is currently 2.6.32, which is the one you are using.
You can find the latest sources at git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/shemminger/iproute2.git . More info is available [here](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/iproute2). You probably have to compile it yourself.